# Js variable to PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

i'm going to post more than one data, but my code does not working could you help me find error

The PHP code is: In here is it right $_POST['product_more'];?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
for($i=0;$i<$product_more_count1;$i++){
$common->name =  $_POST['product_more<?php echo $i ?>'];
$common->en_name=$_POST['product_more_value<?php echo $i ?>'];

$common->savequickSelect();
}
}
```

My JS code is:Ih here when i click add bottom this js adds input forms. In here can i use PHP?. i have been used php like  .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var product_more_count=1;
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('.add_product_more').click(function() {
if(product_more_count<10)
{
$(".product_more_ul").append('<li style="list-style:none">'
                          + '<input placeholder="<?php if($_SESSION['lang']=='en') echo 'Eg : Color, size';

else echo 'Өнгө, Хэмжээ г/м';
 ?>" name="product_more[]" type="text"  style="margin-bottom:5px;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input placeholder="<?php if($_SESSION['lang']=='en') echo 'mangolian';

else echo 'mangolian';
 ?>" name="product_more_value[]" type="text" style="margin-top:0px;" />'
                          + '<a href="#" class="remove_product_more" ><img src="assets/images/removebtn.jpg" width="66" height="20" /></a>'
                          + '</li>');
product_more_count+=1;
<?php $product_more_count1=$product_more_count1+1;?>
}
return false;
});
$('.remove_product_more').live('click', function() {
$(this).parent().remove();
product_more_count-=1;
<?php $product_more_count1=$product_more_count1-1;?>
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

The input form is: in here i have tried to user could add input field as hi want

```
<form action="quick1.php" method="post">
<table width="621" class="form">
<tr>
  <td > More Details:  </td>
  <td >
<ul>
     <li  style="list-style:none">
<input name="product_more<?php echo $product_more_count1 ?>" type="text"/>

<input name="product_more_value<?php echo $product_more_count1 ?>" type="text"/>
     </li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="add_product_more"><img src="assets/images/add1btn.jpg" width="47" height="20" /></a></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input value="" type="submit" name="submit" id="prod_submit" class="submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: You can't use <?php ?> inside <script> tag

Comment: $common->name =  $_POST['product_more<?php echo $i ?>']; // you can't insert wrapped php code inside nested php code

Comment: ok how can i do this?